# epoll is built for Linux and not intended for usage on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, windows-10, epoll

I am trying to run a project in `visual studio code`. My operating system is `Windows 10` and I am using `node.js` version `12.13` and `npm` version `6.12`. Part of the program runs on a `raspberry pi`.

Before running `npm start` I previously installed `npm install epoll` which was successful.

After installing the necessary modules, there seems to be a last error that I am not sure how to take care. I am attaching the print screen of the terminal below:

[image: output]

I have been trying to find out a possible answer, for example I went on the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/epoll) and followed the instruction but I get the same output.

After more research I came across this [source](https://github.com/fivdi/epoll/issues/31) that makes me think that this module could be deprecated or that an alternative exists.

Please point in the right direction on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use that [epoll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/epoll) module in non Linux system. It is only available in Linux based system.

**As the documentation says:**

> Note that although it should be possible to install epoll on non-Linux
>   systems the functionality offered by epoll is only available on Linux
>   systems.

Comment: thanks for reading the question. Is there an equivalent for `Windows` for that module?

Comment: I don't think there is any. You might find C/C++ implementation of it. Then, you can create a JavaScript wrapper. Its hard work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer